# Intersection of 2D polygons

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that are OpenCV **convex hulls** and I want to check for intersection without creating for loops or creating images and performing `numpy.bitwise_and` on them, both of which are quite slow in Python. The arrays look like this:

```
[[[x1 y1]]
 [[x2 y2]]
 [[x3 y3]]
...
 [[xn yn]]]
```

Considering [[x1 y1]] as one single element, I want to perform intersection between two numpy ndarrays. How can I do that? I have found a few questions of similar nature, but I could not figure out the solution to this from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I did to get the job done:

```
import Polygon, numpy

# Here I extracted and combined some contours and created a convex hull from it.
# Now I wanna check whether a contour acquired differently intersects with this hull or not.

for contour in contours:  # The result of cv2.findContours is a list of contours
    contour1 = contour.flatten()
    contour1 = numpy.reshape(contour1, (int(contour1.shape[0]/2),-1))
    poly1 = Polygon.Polygon(contour1)

    hull = hull.flatten()  # This is the hull is previously constructued
    hull = numpy.reshape(hull, (int(hull.shape[0]/2),-1))
    poly2 = Polygon.Polygon(hull)

    if (poly1 & poly2).area()<= some_max_val:
        some_operations
```

I had to use for loop, and this altogether looks a bit tedious, although it gives me expected results. Any better methods would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17):

You can use a view of the array as a single dimension to the intersect1d function like this:

```
def multidim_intersect(arr1, arr2):
    arr1_view = arr1.view([('',arr1.dtype)]*arr1.shape[1])
    arr2_view = arr2.view([('',arr2.dtype)]*arr2.shape[1])
    intersected = numpy.intersect1d(arr1_view, arr2_view)
    return intersected.view(arr1.dtype).reshape(-1, arr1.shape[1])
```

This creates a view of each array, changing each row to a tuple of values. It then performs the intersection, and changes the result back to the original format. Here's an example of using it:

```
test_arr1 = numpy.array([[0, 2],
                         [1, 3],
                         [4, 5],
                         [0, 2]])

test_arr2 = numpy.array([[1, 2],
                         [0, 2],
                         [3, 1],
                         [1, 3]])

print multidim_intersect(test_arr1, test_arr2)
```

This prints:

```
[[0 2]
 [1 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! This would be perfect if all the points in the perimeter were in the numpy arrays. However, in convex hulls, I think only a few points are passed as guides. But intersection, as it means in this case, is common values in both areas, which may not be common inside the numpy arrays themselves. I just read my post above, and realized that I did not mention this at all. I am sorry for that.

Comment: When I apply your view on my numpy, it looks like this:

[[[(x1,)(y1,)]][[(x2,)(y2,)]]...[[(xn,)(yn,)]]]

Whereas what we really need is this:


[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), ..., (xn,yn)]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you just have an extra axis for some reason? Can you just reshape it first with ``test_arr1.reshape(len(test_arr1), 2)``? That will avoid a copy.

Comment: Actually, the array is generated by opencv function, and it does not even require me to set a dtype or dimension, so I have no control over how it is shaped. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: that's testing for _points_ being in common. this is about the intersection of the entire shapes described by the polygons/contours -- this question shouldn't be the top answer because it's **wrong**. how did 18 people think this was a correct answer, except if they didn't read the question well enough...

Answer (score 4):

you can use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Polygon/2.0.4, here is an example:

```
>>> import Polygon
>>> a = Polygon.Polygon([(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)])
>>> b = Polygon.Polygon([(0.3,0.3), (0.3, 0.6), (0.6, 0.3)])
>>> a & b
Polygon:
  <0:Contour: [0:0.60, 0.30] [1:0.30, 0.30] [2:0.30, 0.60]>
```

To convert the result of cv2.findContours to Polygon point format, you can:

```
points1 = contours[0].reshape(-1,2)
```

This will convert the shape from (N, 1, 2) to (N, 2)

Following is a full example:

```
import Polygon
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import bytescale

y, x = np.ogrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]

f1 = bytescale(np.exp(-x**2 - y**2), low=0, high=255)
f2 = bytescale(np.exp(-(x+1)**2 - y**2), low=0, high=255)


c1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours((f1>120).astype(np.uint8), 
                                       cv2.cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c2, hierarchy = cv2.findContours((f2>120).astype(np.uint8), 
                                       cv2.cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


points1 = c1[0].reshape(-1,2) # convert shape (n, 1, 2) to (n, 2)
points2 = c2[0].reshape(-1,2)

import pylab as pl
poly1 = pl.Polygon(points1, color="blue", alpha=0.5)
poly2 = pl.Polygon(points2, color="red", alpha=0.5)
pl.figure(figsize=(8,3))
ax = pl.subplot(121)
ax.add_artist(poly1)
ax.add_artist(poly2)
pl.xlim(0, 100)
pl.ylim(0, 100)

a = Polygon.Polygon(points1)
b = Polygon.Polygon(points2)
intersect = a&b # calculate the intersect polygon

poly3 = pl.Polygon(intersect[0], color="green") # intersect[0] are the points of the polygon
ax = pl.subplot(122)
ax.add_artist(poly3)
pl.xlim(0, 100)
pl.ylim(0, 100)
pl.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is this method really fast? I need to keep checking for intersection every frame as I capture, and system resource is not very high.

Comment: When I try to create polygon from an opencv contour or convex hull, this is the error I get:

`cPolygon.Error: Invalid polygon or contour for operation`

The format that you specified is not the format I have (shown in my original post). I assume some modifications might be necessary, but cannot imagine how it could be done.

Comment: please post some sample data.

Comment: This is how I make contours: `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sourceimage, cv2.cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`
After that, when I do this:`for contour in contours: print contour.dtype, contour.shape, contour`, I get this: `int32 (84, 1, 2)
[[[23  1]]

 [[23  4]]

 [[22  5]]

 [[23  5]]

......

 [[28  5]]

 [[24  1]]]`

The result would be the same for cv2.convexHull() if I used it instead of cv2.findContours()

Comment: As mentioned [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9271260/1062484), if I could change the view to a simple list of tuples, then Polygon.Polygon() would accept it, but I can't seem to get it :(

Comment: you can pass contour.reshape(-1, 2) to Polygon.Polygon()。I updated the answer with a full example.

Answer (score -1):

**inspired by jiterrace's answer**

I came across this post while working with [Udacity deep learning class(](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb)trying to find the overlap between training and test data).

I am not familiar with "view" and found the syntax a bit hard to understand, probably the same when I try to communicate to my friends who think in "table".
My approach is basically to flatten/reshape the ndarray of shape (N, X, Y) into shape (N, X*Y, 1).

```
print(train_dataset.shape)
print(test_dataset.shape)
#(200000L, 28L, 28L)
#(10000L, 28L, 28L)
```

1). INNER JOIN (easier to understand, slow)

```
import pandas as pd

%%timeit -n 1 -r 1
def multidim_intersect_df(arr1, arr2):
    p1 = pd.DataFrame([r.flatten() for r in arr1]).drop_duplicates()
    p2 = pd.DataFrame([r.flatten() for r in arr2]).drop_duplicates()
    res = p1.merge(p2)
    return res
inters_df = multidim_intersect_df(train_dataset, test_dataset)
print(inters_df.shape)
#(1153, 784)
#1 loop, best of 1: 2min 56s per loop
```

2). SET INTERSECTION (fast)

```
%%timeit -n 1 -r 1
def multidim_intersect(arr1, arr2):
    arr1_new = arr1.reshape((-1, arr1.shape[1]*arr1.shape[2])) # -1 means row counts are inferred from other dimensions
    arr2_new = arr2.reshape((-1, arr2.shape[1]*arr2.shape[2]))
    intersected = set(map(tuple, arr1_new)).intersection(set(map(tuple, arr2_new)))  # list is not hashable, go tuple
    return list(intersected)  # in shape of (N, 28*28)

inters = multidim_intersect(train_dataset, test_dataset)
print(len(inters))
# 1153
#1 loop, best of 1: 34.6 s per loop
```

Comment: that's testing for _points_ being in common. this is about the intersection of the entire shapes described by the polygons/contours