# Intersect two numpy index arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, set-intersection

Suppose I have two images that are thresholded differently, and I want to find the set intersection of indexes over both threshold, in other words all the indexes that are in both lists. Assume the dimensions are equal, so there is nothing to worry about for that.

```
img1 = #something
img2 = #something slightly different
indexes1 = np.nonzero(img1)
indexes2 = np.nonzero(img2)
index_intersection = #???
```

How can I do this in a way that is easy to understand and in a way that is efficient?

Comment: Assume sample data for `img1` and `img2` and show us the expected output?

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269681/intersection-of-2d-numpy-ndarrays

Comment: @AGML that question is about geometric (also falls under infinite set) intersection, while this one is about finite set intersection. Similar, but different!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for matching nonzero XY indices pairs, you can use boolean ANDing between the nonzero masks of the input arrays and then use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), like so -

```
out = np.nonzero((img1!=0) & (img2!=0))
```

You can verify these results with [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) after getting the linear indices of matches from `img1` and `img2` giving us a second approach to solve the problem at hand , like so -

```
l_intsct = np.intersect1d(np.nonzero(img1.ravel())[0],np.nonzero(img2.ravel())[0])
out = np.unravel_index(l_intsct,img1.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [127]: img1
Out[127]: 
array([[3, 2, 3, 1, 0],
       [3, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 2]])

In [128]: img2
Out[128]: 
array([[1, 1, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [4, 1, 0, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 4, 1, 4]])

In [129]: np.nonzero(img1)
Out[129]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]))

In [130]: np.nonzero(img2)
Out[130]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4]))

In [131]: np.nonzero((img1!=0) & (img2!=0))
Out[131]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4]))

In [132]: l_intsct = np.intersect1d(np.nonzero(img1.ravel())[0],np.nonzero(img2.ravel())[0])

In [133]: np.unravel_index(l_intsct,img1.shape)
Out[133]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Interesting! What if (0,0) is in each?

Comment: @AndrewHundt If `R1,C1 = np.nonzero(img1)` and `R2,C2 = np.nonzero(img2)` and you meant (0,0) as a pair of `R` and `C`, which is already happening in the listed sample, then looking at the output: `R,C = np.nonzero((img1!=0) & (img2!=0))` from the listed solution gives you that pair, right? Or what else do you mean?

Comment: In my use case I tried that command and it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure why.