# Python - return intersection of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays and I am trying to return a new array that equals the intersection of my original two arrays. The two original arrays should be of the same length. For example, if I have:

`arr1 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])`

`arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])`

I should get:

`intersectedArr = ([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255])`

However, if I have:

`arr1 = np.array([(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)])`

`arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])`

I should get

`([(255, 255, 255)])`

So far i've tried:

`intersectedArr = np.intersect1d(arr1, arr2)`

but this returns `[255]` instead of the expected `([(255, 255, 255)])`

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific? how about ([(100,200,100),(100,100,100)]) and ([(100,200,200]),(200,100,200)])?

Comment: Also, please give examples of what you've tried. Thanks!

Comment: hi - the arrays should be of same length. I tried `intersectedArr = np.intersect1d(arr1, arr2)`

Comment: I mean, if you have [a,b,c] and [a,c,c] will it return [a,c] or nothing?

Comment: yep correct @BoboCarr

Comment: which one is correct?

Comment: it should return [a, c] @BoboCarr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how big your arrays will get, but if they remain fairly small, this could work:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])
arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])
intersectedArr = []

for a1, a2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
    if np.array_equal(a1, a2):
        intersectedArr.append(a1)
print(np.array(intersectedArr))

arr1 = np.array([(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)])
arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])
intersectedArr = []

for a1, a2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
    if np.array_equal(a1, a2):
        intersectedArr.append(a1)
print(np.array(intersectedArr))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep duplicates, like in your examples, you can use a list comprehension:

```
def intersection(list_a, list_b):
    return [ e for e in list_a if e in list_b ]
```

which produces:

```
in:
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
out:
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]

in:
    [(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)]
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
out:
    [(255, 255, 255)]
```

If you want uniquie combinations between the lists (sets) though:

```
def intersection(a, b):
    return list(set(a).intersection(b))
```

which produces:

```
in:
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
out:
    [(255, 255, 255)]

in:
    [(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)]
    [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
out:
    [(255, 255, 255)]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

how about a `numpy` answer?

```
import numpy as np


arr1 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 25)])  # changed some to 25
arr2 = np.array([(255, 25, 255), (255, 255, 25)])

arr1[np.where(arr1==arr2)]

array([255, 255, 255, 255,  25])
```

2nd example

```
arr1 = np.array([(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)])
arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])

arr1[np.where(arr1==arr2)]

array([255, 255, 255])
```

Comment: This one is best for me, since you don't need to write iteration.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This assumes `[a, b, c]` and `[b, c, a]` gives `[a, b, c]`, that is the order of elements is ignored.

OK, I've done a little experimenting and this might be what you are after. Given:

```
arr1a = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])
arr1b = np.array([(100, 100, 100), (255, 255, 255)])
arr2 = np.array([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)])
```

Then we can find an intersection with:

```
np.array([item in arr2 for item in arr1a])
```

ie, for each element in `arr1a`, check to see it appears in `arr2` also. This gives a result of:

```
>>> array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Similarly:

```
np.array([item in arr2 for item in arr1b])
>>> array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Now, we can use this result to pick the common values from the original lists:

```
mask = np.array([item in arr2 for item in arr1a])
arr1a[mask]
>>> array([[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]])
```

And:

```
mask = np.array([item in arr2 for item in arr1b])
arr1b[mask]
>>> array([[255, 255, 255]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger arrays it might help to use pandas' groupby and cumcount:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1)

In [12]: df1["cumcount"] = df1.groupby([0, 1, 2]).cumcount()

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
     0    1    2  cumcount
0  100  100  100         0
1  255  255  255         0

In [14]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2)

In [15]: df2["cumcount"] = df2.groupby([0, 1, 2]).cumcount()

In [16]: df2
Out[16]:
     0    1    2  cumcount
0  255  255  255         0
1  255  255  255         1
```

Now a merge gets you the array you desire:

```
In [21]: df1.merge(df1).iloc[:, :3].values
Out[21]:
array([[100, 100, 100],
       [255, 255, 255]])

In [22]: df1.merge(df2).iloc[:, :3].values
Out[22]: array([[255, 255, 255]])

In [23]: df2.merge(df2).iloc[:, :3].values
Out[23]:
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to compare against rows instead of elements, so it`s a matter of 2D array. I would recommend an improvement of **intersect1d** which is intersection of 2D numpy arrays. I found a good solution here [Intersection of 2D numpy ndarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269681/intersection-of-2d-numpy-ndarrays).

```
def multidim_intersect(arr1, arr2):
    arr1_view = arr1.view([('',arr1.dtype)]*arr1.shape[1])
    arr2_view = arr2.view([('',arr2.dtype)]*arr2.shape[1])
    intersected = numpy.intersect1d(arr1_view, arr2_view)
    return intersected.view(arr1.dtype).reshape(-1, arr1.shape[1])
```

The code above convert the shape of the original array, combine them row-wise, and then convert it back to 2-dim shape.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.